# Cannot create kie session

Tags: session, drools, kie

I created new package in Drools examples and I am trying to create kiesession by:

```
KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
final KieContainer kc = kieServices.getKieClasspathContainer();
final KieSession ksession = kc.newKieSession("RecordKS");
```

however created ksession is null . It is not null when I run other examples provided by drools

Answer (score 0):

Something that is not well explained in the documentation is that, if there is an error in the creation of a `KieBase`, Drools will not complain. You have to manually check for errors:

```
KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
final KieContainer kc = kieServices.getKieClasspathContainer();

//Check for errors
Results results = kc.validate();
if (results.hasMessages(Message.Level.ERROR)){
  //notify about errors
}
```

My guess is that you do have some error that is preventing the `KieBase` to be created and that's why the `KieSession` returned is null.

Hope it helps,